# my keyboard doesn't respond when i try to reset a lost administrative password

Tags: server

My keyboard stops responding when i get to

```
Enter new UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:
passwd: password updated successfully
root@ubuntu:~#
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: How do you know that its not responding?

Comment: Your passwords will not be displayed when you type them in. are you still getting no response when you reach the `root@ubuntu:~#` prompt?

Answer (score 0):

When you get to that point, it doesn't show the password for security resons. So keep on typing, and don't mind the screen. It should change it.

Comment: ok, i'll try it

Comment: I do not see my courser moving when i try to type the new password,i continue to type pw and retyped it but got " authentication manipulation error". num lock lights up on my keyboard but if i hit caps lock it doesn't. If i wanted to delete a password eg: profile  joe, What is the correct way to type that command? passwd joe-d,--delete  ??

Comment: i am trying to delete the password with passwd -d (profile name) but it says "cannot lock etc/shadow try again later".. what can i do?